using promtool to check alerts file meant for patching K8s
We have a microservice environment where each service has its own git, and in that git its own alerts yml for prometheus
We are using [kubectl patch configmap to put] all said alerts together on the prometheus server.
When I try and run promtool check rules {ALERTS_FILE} I get this error:
Checking ./prometheus/****.yml
  FAILED:
yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 1: field data not found in type rulefmt.RuleGroups

I believe it's related to the fact our file starts with
data:
  ****.yml: |
    groups:
      - name: ****
        rules:

Is there a way to order promtool to skip the first two lines and jump straight to the actual rules section?
thanks

Your file appears to be a Kubernetes ConfigMap containing data that maps filenames (e.g. ****.yml) to Prometheus Alerting Rules YAML config.
Using Python, you can parse the ConfigMap YAML file, extracting (from data) each filename and Alerting Rule config and run these through Promtool:
check_rules.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import sys
import yaml

RUNTIME = "podman"
PROMETHEUS = "docker.io/prom/prometheus:v2.55.1"
TOOL = "promtool"

file = sys.stdin.read()

args = [
    RUNTIME,
    "run",
    "--interactive",
    "--rm",
    f"--entrypoint={TOOL}",
    PROMETHEUS,
    "check",
    "rules",
]

config_map = yaml.safe_load(file)

for filename, rules_yaml in config_map["data"].items():
  process = subprocess.run(args,
    input=rules_yaml,
    capture_output=True,
    text=True,
  )
  print(f"{filename}\n{process.stdout}")


NOTE Because this uses yaml, you'll need to pip install pyyaml in your environment before you can run the Python file.

For example:
echo '
data:
  example.yml: |
    groups:
    - name: example
      rules:
      - alert: HighRequestLatency
        expr: job:request_latency_seconds:mean5m{job="myjob"} > 0.5
        for: 10m
        labels:
          severity: page
        annotations:
          summary: High request latency
' | ./check_rules.py

Yields:
example.yml
Checking standard input
  SUCCESS: 1 rules found


wow, thanks! I'll give it a try
